# Iteration using ExecutorSErvice, Runnable

Tags: java, iteration, executorservice, runnable

In a service implementation following is the implementation

```
    if(usernames != null && usernames.size() > 0) {

        operationId = bulkUpdateAuditLogRepository.getLatestOperationId()
        for(String username: usernames) {
            executorService.submit(new BackgroundTask() {
                @Override
                public void doTask() {
                    deactivateUserInternal(username, operationId)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Also
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

anyhow while iterating the loop only the last username of any array ['AAAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC'], only the value CCCC is taken up by the runnable BackgroundTask instance.
Just want to know what is missing in the iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the* runnable BackgroundTask instance"? With the specified example data, your code creates and submits three separate tasks, one for each element of `usernames` (and all with the same `operationId`).  I'm inclined to think that the iteration itself is not the problem, and we haven't enough information to guess what else it might be.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JohnBollinger, it was the missing information in the logs as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundTask mentioned was not a java.util.concurrent.Callable, after such implementation able to get the executing in an async manner.